# Checking the file existence in other directories

Tags: c, directory

I have been using `access(file_name, 0) == -1` to check whether the user input `file_name` exists in the directory or not. But this method works in the current working directory. 
I wonder if there is a way I could know whether the `file_name` exists in another directory or not so I can move it to that directory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/param.h>

    void MoveFile(void)

    {
        DIR *directory;
        FILE *Temp_file;
        struct dirent *read_direcory;
        char inserted_file_name[25]="/", intro[3]="/";
        char *file_name = malloc(sizeof(*file_name));
        char Current_path[200], destination_path[1024],relocating_path[1024] = "/";

        int counter;
        directory = opendir("./");

        if (directory != NULL && getcwd(Current_path, sizeof(Current_path)) !=NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "\nYour current working directory: %s \n", Current_path);
            counter = 0;
            while ((read_direcory = readdir(directory)) != NULL){
                    printf("%d %s\n",counter,read_direcory -> d_name);
                    counter++;

        }
        closedir(directory);
        }else{
        perror("\nUnable to find the directory!");
        }

        printf("\nEnter just the name of the file you wish to move from above (e.g) file.txt.\n");
        scanf("%s",file_name);
        strcat(inserted_file_name, file_name);

        printf("\nWrite the directory where %s file is located (e.g) /Users/Sam\n", file_name);
        scanf("%s", relocating_path);
        strcat(relocating_path, inserted_file_name);

//I want to know here whether it exists in that directory or not.

        printf("\nWrite the name of the directory where you want to move your file to (e.g) /Users/Sam/Pictures:\n");
        scanf("%s", destination_path);//file_name
        strcat(destination_path, inserted_file_name);

        if (rename(relocating_path, destination_path)){
            perror(NULL);
            getchar();

            }
        printf("\nMoving %s file was successful!:D\n", file_name);

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just try to `fopen` it with `mode = "r"`?

Comment: Aside: `char *file_name = malloc(sizeof(*file_name));` allocates **one byte** of memory (and is not `free`ed) anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane I know I have to free it, I usually do it at the end, I didn't write it there though because I have not finished the code yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to see if a file exists is to use the `stat` system call:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

{
    ...
    struct stat sb;

    if (stat(destination_path, &sb) == -1) {
        if (errno == ENOENT) {
           // File does not exist
        }
    }
}
```